# How can I change this 2 lines of HTML so that i can put it into my CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors, selector, target

How can i target the red text in CSS? I need to change the color of all the red text to orange:

`<span style="color: #dc143c;"><strong>Red text that must be Orange</strong></span>`

I tried with the following, but i don't really know how should I write it to make it work..

```
span[style="color: #dc143c;"] {
    color:#f7941d !important;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cant you put an `id` to all such `span` elements?

Comment: @Sushovan Well that wouldnt help at all. You should read up about `id` and `class`.

Comment: They are thousands.. But they are all bold and red, any idea?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbeRgB it works fine, as expected, both on chrome and firefox

Comment: You got the solution. Though, it's better to say that you should use classes instead of inline-style. Using classes you'll avoid this "bad code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the style tag from your html completely and use classes instead.

```
<span class="colored"><strong>colored text</strong></span>
```

then select the class in your css instead

```
.colored {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the all red code in `<span>` tag then in css target the `<span>` and give them class tag to change it color to red code given below

```
<span class="red-text">this is red text</span>
```

css code:

```
.red-text {color:#f7941d;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your Red Text an ID or Class of color-change etc.

```
<span class="color-change" style="color: #dc143c;"><strong>Red text that must be Orange</strong></span>
```

now in your css

```
.color-change {
    color:#f7941d !important;
    }
```

One More Thing not use inline css because inline css has maximum priority if you use inline css must use !important keyword to change color.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <span id="change">this is red text</span>
```

css code:

```
  #change {
 color:#f7941d;
 }
```

Try this Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Add the class orange at the strong tag:

```
<span style="color: #dc143c;"><strong class="orange">Red text that must be Orange</strong></span>
```

In the .css file:

```
.orange {
```

color: #f7941d !important;
}

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be easier to use a class or id for the span and target it whenever you want using javascript or jquery. example

Red text must be orange

with jquery you can do this:
    $('.OrangeRedSpan').css('color': #FE9A2E);

Comment: He needs to change *all reds* not just one